# Perl ImageMagick: how to disable printing of command output?

Tags: perl, imagemagick, perlmagick

I have a Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Image::Magick;

my $temp_filename = 'temp.webp';

my $im = Image::Magick->new;
my $m = $im->Read($temp_filename);
```

When I run it from the command line, I get:

```
$ perl test.cgi
Decoded /tmp/magick-324583Dvjs7UCnJGp. Dimensions: 450 x 300. Now saving...
Saved file /tmp/magick-324589ZiUphKo482g
$
```

I expect (and want):

```
$ perl test.cgi
$
```

What gives?

Comment: Is that the actual script that produces that output? The file name is different for starters, and the code doesn't do any writing of the image...

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the script provided, even if I add a `$im->write('foo.jpg');`. Works fine on my system, without any output. Please provide a minimal *working* script that demonstrates the problem, and give us some information about your system (OS, Perl version, ImageMagick library version, Image::Magick version).

Comment: This is the EXACT script I am using to get this output, including the filename in the code, and the filenames in the output. OS is CentOS 7, Perl 5.16.3, ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16, Image::Magick version 6.9.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding

```
$im->SetAttribute(quiet=>1);
```

fixed this issue for me.

Final script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Image::Magick;

my $temp_filename = 'temp.webp';

my $im = Image::Magick->new;
$im->SetAttribute(quiet=>1);
my $m = $im->Read($temp_filename);
```